# Calculating Periodic values from YTD

Tags: sql, window, teradata, lag, periodic

I have a dataset which has 12 columns which includes an amount column which is arriving as YTD.
I need to convert the Ytd into a periodic and populate in a new column.
We are receiving 300-400k records per month with the month column changing and the respective amount column.

So i need to convert this amount column into periodic values.
For ex for jan the periodic should be same as YTD.
For feb it should be the difference of Feb and Jan.
For mar it should be the difference of Mar and Feb  and so on..
We have to consider all the columns while calculating the difference between the months.. (Assuming same amount of data will be populated every month).

I tried lag but still I can see some error.

Ps: calculating YTD is not required but the periodic

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from SQL standard compliant.)

Comment: I am using Teradata sql

Comment: `ytd - lag(ytd,1,0) over (partition by whatever order by datecol)` should work (as long as there's no missing month)